# When should a function return what?

Tags: c, return, return-value, return-type

I'm a bit confused about the return type of a function, specifically when to return what. If we have any arbitrary function, let's say min(x,y), which should return according to the if statements, what should I return outside of their scope, which is required by the function's declaration. I've learned that it is common to use "return 0" or "return 1" but I don't understand why that is, and why it can't just return either of the if's return statements.

```
// compute difference largest - smallest
int   diff(x, y)
{
   if (x > y)
    return x - y;
   if (y > x)
    return y - x;
   if (x == y)
    return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: A function should return the value you want to return to the caller. What that value is depends on the function’s purpose. Often 0 and 1 are used to indicate success and failure, or failure and success, or false and true. Often a function returns a value that is computed from its parameters. In the case of a `min` function, `min` probably stands for “minimum”, and it should return the minimum value of its two parameters. A `min` function does not normally return 1 in the case of equality (unless the two numbers happen to be 1).

Comment: A function to return the absolute difference of two values should not be called `min`. It could be called `AbsoluteDifference` or `absdiff` or something along those lines. In simplest form, such a function would return zero if the two numbers are equal. If you want to return one for equal numbers, you might call it `ClampedAbsoluteDifference`.

Comment: Note that, in modern C, `int min(x, y)` is not a proper declaration. You need types for the parameters, such as `int min(int x, int y)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but why do I have to declare it twice; if I want it to return the difference. Why doesn't the function skip the return 1, and only return either of the if's, if it is true, and terminate?

Comment: @Mike declare what twice? The `return 1;` will never be executed because all three possible cases are handled before. Therefore you can remove the `return 1;`. Or best write the function as suggested by EricPostpischil's answer.

Comment: Note that the calculation is subject to overflow (undefined behaviour) if, for example, `y == INT_MIN + 3` and `x == INT_MAX - 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to make sure that you return something. If you have returns inside of if statements, such as you have, how is the compiler going to tell if you have covered all cases?

Even if you do something like the code below, how is the compiler going to know that you will return in all circumstances? Because of that this code will throw an error:

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y)
        return x - y;
    if (y > x)
        return y - x;
    if (x==y)
        return 1;
}
```

How can you combat this? You can write another return at the end of the function, as you have. Now the compiler know that you will return a value no matter what happens.

However there are better ways to make sure that you will always return a value. For example, you can use an else statement as a catch-all:

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y)
        return x - y;
    if (y > x)
        return y - x;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Because the else is guaranteed to catch all cases, the compiler is happy about it, and will not throw any errors.

Comment: The first version of the `min` function will not  throw an error, and `int min(x, y)` is wrong anyway. And there are no exceptions in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: What's wrong with `int min(x, y)`?  It isn't a prototype, granted, and it shouldn't have been written by anyone in the current millennium, and it probably should be `int min(x, y) int x, y; { …function body… }`, but there a nuances which I'm not seeing in your comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I get an error thrown (control reaches end of non-void function) on gcc. As for the deceleration, I copied from question and forgot to fix. Will do so now.

Comment: @hat strange, I don't get the error: check here:  https://www.godbolt.org/z/On5feX

Comment: Even if a function’s return type is not void, the C standard does not require it to return a value, as long as the caller does not attempt to use the return value. (This can be useful for a function that either gets a value or sets a value, depending on a parameter it is given. The “set a value” path does not need to return a value.) So a compiler can warn if there is a control path without a `return`, but, when it is in standard-compliant mode, it must successfully translate such a function.

Comment: @hat I get the warning here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/On5feX when I remove `else
        return 1;` Which compiler version do you have?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I didn't check the code in your last comment. The behaviour is the same then.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Gcc 7.3.0 compiling for C99

Comment: @hat very strange. Maybe your IDE (if you have one) passes other flags to the compiler? What is your exact command line for the compiler?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Oh, is that what you were wondering about? I meant -Wall was the only warnings option, I compile with -c and build with -o on standalone files (default Geany build)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188436/discussion-between-jabberwocky-and-hat).

Answer (score 3):

- If `X` is bigger than `Y`, return `X-Y`  *(obvious)*
- If `Y` is bigger than `X`, return `Y-X`  *(also obvious)*
- If `X` and `Y` are ***equal***, what do you think should be returned?
  If they're equal, both `X-Y` and `Y-X` are `0`, so it doesn't really matter, does it?

Your final clause could be written any of:

```
return x-y;
return y-x;
return 0;
```

Because they two values are equal, they will ALL evaluate to `0`.

The important part is to make sure the **contract** of the function is maintained.
According to the comments, the function claims it will return the difference between the two values.  So it should return the difference ***in all cases***, whether the bigger value is X, Y, or they are equal.

The name of your function is extremely misleading.  Because it is named `min`, it implies it will return the *minimum* value, not the difference.  You should change the name of the function to something like `diff` or `delta` for clarity.

---

Ultimately, the simpler way to write the function would be:

```
// compute largest - smallest
int diff(int x, int y)
{
   if (x > y)
    return x - y;   // Handles X is bigger than Y
   else
    return y - x;   // Handles Y bigger than X, *or* X and Y are the same.
}
```

Finally, some very short versions that I would consider better.

```
int diff(int x, int y) { return x>y? x-y:y-x; }
int diff(int x, int y) { return abs(x-y);     }
```

Comment: Yeah but If i run it with printf, it returns 1. Why is that?

Comment: @Mike When you run it with two equal values it return `1` because you told it to return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

For a function that's computing the difference between two values, you would only return 1 if the difference between those two values was 1, 0 if they were equal.

There's a school of programming that says it's better to have a single return at the end of the function, rather than multiple returns scattered throughout.  Instead of returning the difference in each branch, compute and store that difference, and return it at the end of the function:

```
int diff( int x, int y );
{
  int delta = 0;

  if ( x >= y )
    delta = x - y;
  else 
    delta = y - x;

  return delta;
}
```

Like most programming rules, there are exceptions.  There are times where you *want* to exit immediately if a certain condition isn't met.  Knowing when which approach is the better one is a matter of experience.

Answer (score -1):

The return type of the function is specified in the definition, `int` in your case.
Actually you need to specify the type of input arguments (`x, y`) and then the type of the output is usually derived from their type - like 2/3 cases in your function and the last one is integer (`0`).

Remark:
You also need to choose better name for the function.

Comment: The `int min(x, y) { …function body… }` is the non-prototype (K&R or pre-standard) C definition.  Current versions of the standard still allow it, though the notation is marked obsolescent (though C99 and later might demand `int min(x, y) int x, y; { …function body… }`).